# CSHTML Confirm Delete prior to deleting database record

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on updating a form for our website. At the beginning of the code I have an @{} code block that runs updates on a database.

I now need to be able to delete a record from that database when a Cancel button is clicked. Prior to doing that I need to confirm that the user actually wants to delete the record they have started.

In C# I could use a MessageBox or DialogBox with an OK and CANCEL option, but what can I use inside the @{} code to do the same thing? I'm afraid that if I use JavaScript that the record will still be deleted if the user clicks the Cancel button.

Here is my Cancel button code:

```
if(!Request["btnCancel"].IsEmpty()){
    var deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [dbo] WHERE ID=@0";
    db.Execute(deleteCommand, Userid);
    Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

Where dbo is the name of my database.

Comment: Feels strange to have this logic in your view.  Why is this not a controller POST action?

Comment: thank you for that question. The reason is our previous web master published the website, and a few months later was fired. He took all the source code and deleted it, leaving us only with the published files on our production server. I'm working on building a new website, but our agencies need updates to the current website while the new one is being worked on. Hopefully that answers your question. Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense. Sounds like a tough situation overall

Comment: It pretty much sucks to be in this situation. Is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: You can use javascript `window.confirm` or a bootstrap modal to ask for the confirmation using client side JavaScript and when user confirm, allow the normal form post to happen, else return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shyju for tipping me off to the answer. It was much more simple than I had anticipated. I was using an input tag, and luckily, it does have a built in onclick="" attribute. I simply did the following:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnCancel"
    class="btn btn-default btn-large"
    value="Cancel Application"
    formnovalidate 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel your application?\n\nThis process cannot be undone, and any information you have entered will be lost.');"/>
```

Now when the button is clicked I get a prompt with an OK or CANCEL button. The OK button continues the posting action while the CANCEL button returns to the page without posting or modifying the page and it's contents.

I hope this helps someone else.